# To find the work done by the force $F(x,y) = \left \langle7y -7xe^{14x},\tan^{-1}(14y)-4x\right \rangle$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, vector-analysis

To find the work done by the force $$F(x,y) = \left \langle 7y -7xe^{14x},\tan^{-1}(14y)-4x \right \rangle$$ moving an object counterclockwise along the boundary of the triangle formed by the points $(0,0),(1,0),(1,4)$.

Here I used Green's Theorem:

$$W = \int P \, dx + Q \, dy = \iint \frac{\delta Q}{\delta x} - \frac{\delta P}{\delta y} \, dA = \int_0^1 \int_0^{4x} -11\,  dy \, dx = -22.$$

Is the solution correct?

Comment: Are you supposed to get -11 as the integrand?

Comment: @YTong Thank You.

Comment: I tend to think that there is very little room for you to doubt this is correct, but if you want a quick check, just use a computer applet [like this](https://math.la.asu.edu/~kawski/vfa2/) to prove it yourself. Draw a polygon and check the circulation.

Comment: [Here is its](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/9312897/103107952-1a9fca00-4611-11eb-929c-959cdfd4b894.png) to the degree it is possible to pinpoint the actual coordinates with the mouse.